# Remove all permission (Visual SVN 2.1.2)

Tags: svn, active-directory, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have a very old version of Visual SVN (2.1.2). Today I need to reorganize some folders, so I have to remove all permissions (very very many) of old repo which have been decentralized access in the past. 
And the question is: How to remove all of them? 
Thank you.

[image: Repo]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your VisualSVN Server installation to benefit from the [VisualSVN Server PowerShell cmdlets](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/). There are cmdlets for access rules management such as

- [Get-SvnAccessRule](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule)
- [Add-SvnAccessRule](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Add-SvnAccessRule)
- [Set-SvnAccessRule](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Set-SvnAccessRule)
- [Remove-SvnAccessRule](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Remove-SvnAccessRule)

They will help you.

Note that your current server installation is very-very old. VisualSVN Server 2.1.2 was released more than 9 years ago (on April 26, 2010). The current version is 4.1.x and there were numerous improvements and enhancements in the product since then. Try the latest VisualSVN Server versions - you'll like what you see.